# Meaning of an embedded sentence and how this usage is called (example)

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-patterns

I have stumbled upon on the following sentence, and I do not understand how the bold one is related to the others:

> And here, in Saddoth, beyond the domes and terraces and columns of the
> huge necropolis, **a necromantic flower wherein forgotten lilies live
> again**, there bloomed the superb and sorrowful loveliness of
> Thameera,

What does this sentence (in bold) relate to? If I take it out, the meaning of the whole construction seems to be the same. But I am unsure - is the flower referring to the necropolis, or to Thameera?

Comment: Have you looked up any words in that phrase that you don't know? If so what is it you still don't understand?

Comment: @BoldBen There are no words I do not understand. I am asking how the marked sentence fits it, as it does not seem to be related clearly. Who is the mentioned flower, is it the Thameera? Then why there is present tense in that part, but past simple in the last?

Comment: '[A] necromantic flower wherein forgotten lilies live again' is a descriptive appositive of 'the huge necropolis'. Adding 'which is' would make it a non-defining relative clause.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks a lot, that is exactly the information I needed!

Comment: It may help to see it as a parenthetical expression.

Comment: Note that I've had to consider the apposition to be to 'the huge necropolis'; the whole sentence is clunky, unwieldy. Putting the appositive (as Yosef says, a parenthetical) in dashes would make things clearer, at least.